# How can I handle water in the basement of my stone foundation house?

Tags: water, basement, leak, french-drain

I have an old (1900) row house in a city (no yard on either side). It is a stone foundation. About two months after I moved in, I found water leaking into my basement after heavy rains. It comes in where the wall meets the floor. The water was coming in from one spot, but all the walls appear to becoming discolored/flaking.

It appears that the previous owner put up some rough casting/parging (metal mesh with big bolts in the wall and some concrete/mortar stuff over it) to hide the problem long enough for the home to sell.

I made the discovery ~18 months ago. At the time, I immediately set up a powerful dehumidifier that is running 24/7 and some fans pointed on the trouble areas. I no longer get water pooling/coming in directly.

But the cheap rough casting is flaking and is becoming more and more white/discolored. I have spoken with some contractors about installing a vapor wall + interior french drain system to manage the incoming water.

It seems like that is the best thing I can do in terms of fixing the situation since I can't access anything externally. Some of them also have suggested paneling/rough casting again over any new vapor wall.

**My question is, should I try to remove the old, flaking rough casting before the new french drain + vapor wall is installed?**

I don't want to pay for an expensive interior french drain system only for it to be made ineffective/ clogged/ damaged by the old rough casting falling apart/flaking/crumbling over time. Is that a concern I should have? I know it is a huge pain to remove rough casting (with all the metal mesh and bolts into my stone foundation). But I want to know if that is what is needed to do the job right.

[image]

Comment: Depending on local laws, you might have a case against the old owners if they told you no leaks/did not mention the foundation leaks.  It will depend on when the stone was covered up.  If done years ago, they might have honestly thought it was fixed.  Will probably need french or some drains plus a sump pump to remove the water.

Comment: Yea I will look into contacting the old owner. It seems pretty shady frankly. But I never thought I would have any recourse. I'll look more into that. 
Would you remove the old rough casting before having the french/pump installed?

Comment: I do not know how well it is joined to the wall, so it might just be cracks or it is ready to fall off.  Mesh and bolts, it might stay on for many years.

Comment: Since you can see the mesh & bolts, it seems to me that it would be reasonably straightforward to undo the bolts & pull the mesh. Sure, it'll make a mess, but you do that once with drop cloths in place to catch as much as possible and be done with it.

Comment: The "bolts" aren't exactly something I can fully see or have access to. Bolt is probably the incorrect word entirely. They appear to be more like metal rods. 
Removing it all is definitely something that is doable, just would be an undertaking. So if it's not an issue at all then I would avoid doing it, but if it should be done first then I will make the effort.

Comment: Here are some additional pictures of what is going on: https://imgur.com/a/nz9pKB0

Comment: You've already looked into the regrading and gutters solutions?